# Angular 4 array of strings

Tags: angular, input, ngfor

I'm using reactive form,
I have 2 questions :
I want to use a array of strings as an input that the user can change directly, I have a data model like this

```
export class Work {
    toDos: string[];  
}
```

Q1 : Is it ok to bind a input directly to an array of primitives or should I convert toDos in an array of object with a property name, and always use controls?

Q2 : 
I tried several think, but I can't find a simple way to make it working :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of toDos;let index = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
   <input [(ngModel)]="toDos[index]" placeholder="item" name="word{{index}}">
</div>

 <button (click)="addItem()" type="button">Add an 
Item</button>
<div *ngFor="let item of toDos">
  <label>{{item}}</label>
</div>
```

In the component.ts

```
toDos: string[] =["Todo1","Todo2","Todo3"];
trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
   return index;
 }
 addItem() {
   this.toDos.push('0');
 }
```

The add function works ok but the input is not bind and I don't get any errors,
I can change the value of the input but it's not reflect on {{item}}

Comment: It works for me https://plnkr.co/edit/pOzYm4TNJqCbsnyC2jkk?p=preview

Comment: I found why it was not working, it was not working because it was inside a <form></form>  I don't really know why though. It's ok now, thanks, I'd still be interesting to know if it's best practice to always use array of objects instead of array of primitives, and if it's better to use controlers with formControlName inside input instead of ngModel

Answer (score 3):

Create a simple array as follows:

```
yourArray= new Array();
```

You can add elements to it easily using push function of the Array as follows:

```
yourArray.push(data);
```